# Can I be Tracked?

Tags: iphone, email

I understand a company can track me if I open up an email they sent via the images inside the email.. My question is as follows:

Suppose I donwload the email to my iPhone and don't actually click on the email to view the full email.. Rather I just view the txt that one can see without clicking on the email can they track me? Does the very fact that the email is downloaded to the iPhone iteself allow them to track me?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there are some ways of tracking you when you open the email. although depends on the connections that the company has. it can follow the mail to the final destination, asks your isp (in this case your phone operator) your ip and therefore your location. The thing is there are lot of ways to track you even if you don't open the email. depends on the will and power of the company.